# Map internal with external port of docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a cassandra image that is listening in port `9042`, but since I´m running that image in a virtual machine where has limited external ports I need to map that port to another port.

I try run linking the external port `7017` linked with internal container port `9042` bur it does not work when I run the container and I do a curl

```
docker run --name cassandra -p 9042:7017 -p 9160:9160 --memory=3000m  -d cassandra
```

In the other way around

```
docker run --name cassandra -p 9042:7017 -p 9160:9160 --memory=3000m  -d cassandra
```

Any idea how can I map the internal with external port of the container?.

Regards

Comment: Take a look to [this documentation](https://github.com/wsargent/docker-cheat-sheet#exposing-ports) specially the part which says: "If you're running Docker in Virtualbox, you then need to forward the port there as well, using forwarded_port. Define a range of ports in your Vagrantfile like this so you can dynamically map them:"

Comment: I dont have any access to the VirtualBox configuration. I only have a list of port that are open from outside

Comment: Have you tried adding `EXPOSE 9042` in the Dockerfile?

Comment: There's no Dockerfile, just the official Cassandra image

Comment: I see, actually if you check the [latest dockerfile for cassandra image](https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/blob/986cea9cdfbf38ae611bdfbd14f1b1cc17194e0c/2.1/Dockerfile) they expose a number of ports including 9042...

Comment: The order of your `docker run -p` argument is backwards from what you say in the question.